# Python: how to change dictionary keys using elements of a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm relatively new to Python and I have an issue with my code:

```
days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]


A = list(range(2))
B = list(range(2))

another_dict= {(a, b) : [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]] for a in A for b in B}

my_dict = dict()
for a in A:
    for b in B:
        for c in range(len(another_dict[a, b])):
            for day in range(len(another_dict[a, b][0])):
                my_dict[(a, b, c, day)] = another_dict.get((a, b))[range(len(another_dict[a, b])).index(c)][range(len(another_dict[a, b][0])).index(day)]
```

`day` in my_dictionary key can assume values from 0 to 6 and I want to substitute this values with the respective element of the list `days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]`

(for instance i want to have `(a, b, c, Monday)` instead of `(a, b, c, 0)`)

Is it possible to change the key (a, b, c, day) into a new key (a, b, c, d) for d in days?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the code above the same you can create a new dictionary with the new keys:

```
new_dict = {}
for d in my_dict:
    new_dict[(d[0],d[1],d[2],days[d[3]])] = my_dict[d]
```

Otherwise, change the line:

```
my_dict[(a, b, c, day)] = ...
```

to:

```
my_dict[(a, b, c, days[day])] = ...
```

Output:

```
{(0, 1, 1, 'Friday'): 5, (0, 1, 2, 'Thursday'): 5, (0, 0, 1, 'Saturday'): 6, (1, 0, 1, 'Saturday') ...
```

Comment: Thank you! Excellent answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `enumerate` function. Change this line:

```
for day in range(len(another_dict[a, b][0])):
     my_dict[(a, b, c, days[day])] = ...
```

to:

```
for day, d in enumerate(days):
    my_dict1[(a, b, c, d)] =
```

Since `days` list is of the same size as `another_dict[a, b][0]` I've taken the liberty of simplifying this line a little. But I still find Nick's answer more elegant and straightforward.

Comment: Thank you, great answer! I'm trying to learn python so every solution help me to understand more the language!